# joomla multiple custom fields using xml

Tags: xml, forms, joomla

I need to create some custom fields using xml in a module in joomla 3.0. 
I did somethething like this, shown below.
my mod_mymodule.xml file code for fields is :

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="protection" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_mymodule/include/" label="tagelement">
    <field name="headerTitle" type="text" default="" label="HEADER_TITLE" description="HEADER_TITLE_DESC"/>
    <field name="Title" type="myelem" label="TITLE" id="Title"/>
</fieldset>
</fields>



jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldMyelem extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'myelem'; //the form field type

 protected function getInput()
 {

     return '<input type="text" name="'.$this->name.'" id="'.$this->id.'" label="Title"/><br />'.
        '<input type="text" name="Link" id="Link" label="Link"/><br />'.
        '<input type="text" name="Order" id="order" label="order"/><br />';


 }
```

How to save multiple fields value? please help me

Comment: Is your directory "/modules/mod_careercategory/include/" contains a file named myelem.php ???

Comment: yes I include that file. I can load when it return single field but when I return multiple fields it simply display textbox. Is there any way to load multiple fields with single field type. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Jitendra Khatri now my plan change I only need to save the custom fields value. Please help me.

Comment: Your Custom field is not loaded. Please check with other input like 'file' or 'radio'. Text field is the default field which Joomla! returns, means if you want to load an specific custom field type and that was not found then text field will be visible there.

Comment: No my custom field is loading without any problem when I call normal but I want to load multiple custom fields with single custom field type " type="myelem" ". The above coding working fine but my problem is the fields value not saving to database. I need to save the above mentioned field values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem using module id I retrieved the module params and display the stored value to the respective fields.